# Go to another layout from onListItemClick() in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have a ListView, and I want that when I press an item, go to another screen, which I will later customize, but for the moment I just want go to that window, in this case is about a xml file defined in res/layout/mylayout.xml.

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
}
```

I can't imagine what something else I should do.In LogCat I get some exception that my content has to contain a listview but why this should happens? maybe I want to put something else in that layout, maybe just a textview.Please tell me how could I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is create a different [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), and start it using an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Basically you want to use a different activity for every screen. More information on the Android developers site, which is a great resource

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Here is how you start an Activity from within an Activity using an intent. Assuming the Activity you want to start is called MyActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

also be sure to add the activity to your manifest file inside of the `<application></application>` tags:

```
    <activity
        android:label="My Activity Title"
        android:name=".MyActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Good advice, but could you also tell me how to obtain the intent? I have tried to create new intent = getIntent() in the new created Activity, declare it static and then use startNewActivity(intent) inside onListItemClick(), but I get a nullPointerException.Is this algorithm good?

Answer (score 0):

Proper way would be to fire up anothwer activity ( by firing an intent,  possibly with some extras to commincate clicked item )

Answer (score 0):

You are extendind ListActivity , so view need a ListView . after first itemClick error prompt means now view has been reset by setContentView(R.layout.mylayout), which does not contain a listView .

so Extend activity instead of LsitActivity . inside it write

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewByID(R.id.listView) ;
```

onClikc issue will be resolved .

Comment: thank you for the idea but if I don't extend ListActivity I loose some of my functionality.

Comment: every functionality of ListActivity is possible through A activity . replace getListView() by above code